# Django 1.9 and model changes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

Okay so I have a problem where I designed a model in django and now I need to delete the table in my DB that my model is associated with.  I looked around and could not find any suitable instructions for how to do this django 1.9 so I thought I would ask here.

Basically, I have a model-form like this:

```
class Query(models.Model):
  studyName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  population = models.IntegerField()
  intervention = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  comparison = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  outcome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  outcomeTiming = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  processed_data = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

and I want to change it to be:

```
class Query(models.Model):
  Study_Design = models.TextField()
  Study_Data = models.TextField()
  Study_Tools = models.TextField()
  processed_data = models.TextField()

  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Then change it. What's stopping you? Any errors?

Comment: Are you using migrations? If so, then you should just be able to run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: When I make the changes and run makemigrations I get this message.          You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'Study_Data' to query without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

Comment: It looks like you are making a pretty drastic change to your model and don't really care about any existing data. With that in mind, choose option 1 and enter any value you want for the default. I usually just enter '1' as the one-off default.

Comment: Ah I solved it.  I just needed to add a default parameter in my form call.

Comment: That works too. That's option 2 of the message you were presented with. Glad you got it working.